# Calculated Column Formula Help - IF AND

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a column called `Due Date` and a calculated column called `Task Tracker`.

I am using the following formula in `Task Tracker`, `=IF(AND([Progress Status]="Not Started",[Due Date]<Today),"Overdue",IF(AND([Progress Status]="In Progress",[Due Date]<Today),"Overdue","On Track"))`.

However, this doesn't seem to be working - a task with a due date set for last week hasn't switched over to Overdue and stays on 'On Track'. I am trying to say that if the Due Date is after today and the Progress Status column is either Not Started or In Progress, change the Task Tracker to Overdue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As per design Calculated column values never gets changed if there is no item update takes place.
Whenever an update gets triggered, calculated columns do the condition check and update the value.

In your case you need these calculated column values to change, the only way is an item update should take place (which is not ideal in many scenario's)

Comment: I missed the part about "Switching over", removed my answer. Thanks.